# check if rewrite rule exist

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I created a new rewrite rules in wordpress and at first it runs correctly, and after a while (a few hours) it stop working, when I tried the url, it shows 404 page.
My question is if I check the rewrite rules in `init` action use `$wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();`, will this cause performance issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean a few hours ?

Comment: I mean, at first this new rewrite rule works well, I can use this new rule to find post , but after a few hours (like 10 hours), the same url not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress rewrite rules are hard to debug, if you just search the rule you think is wrong.
The reason is - it uses regular expression, not hard coded rules.

My suggestion is install plugin [rewrite-rules-inspector], then run you url in the plugin UI.
It would give a better idea, which rule cause the problem.

Then, you can fix it `add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', ...)`,  either by remove old rules, or add new rules on top of the rules array;
Remember, the top rule overwrites bottom rules.

Answer (score 2):

More Info is needed ,

but try [`flush_rewrite_rules`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) . extremely important especially with when dealing with CPT.

It is strange however that you see the changes only after a few hours . It should be immediate.

Comment: Yes, as soon as the new rewrite rule not work, I do `flush_rewrite_rules()` and it will work immediately

Comment: Please do not put [flush_rewrite_rules] permanently in your code, it cause lots server resource. You can either run once, then remove it, or install plugin [rewrite-rules-inspector], to flush rules when you need it.